# Why does setting TempData value make the browser change the preferred theme to dark mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages, c#-10.0

I'm working on handling errors so I defaulted one to occur when I post my form:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveAsync()
{
    try
    {
        //var newMemberId = await SaveMemberAsync();
        var newMemberId = 0;

        if (newMemberId <= 0)
        {
            TempData["isError"] = true;
            TempData["errorMsg"] = "...";
            return Page();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["isError"] = true;
        // etc.
        return Page();
    }
}
```

This works fine, however, the form values (particularly the selections from dropdownlists) get cleared.

As a fix, I wanted to pass the submitted model back to the page.

I want to be clear: I don't have the faintest idea what's going on with this problem, but when I add `TempData["Member"] = this.Member;` before the return (as below), the page goes dark mode and doesn't populate the previous selections in the lists.

I don't understand why this happens and I don't have any idea how to diagnose it.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveAsync()
{
    try
    {
        //var newMemberId = await SaveMemberAsync();
        var newMemberId = 0;

        if (newMemberId <= 0)
        {
            TempData["isError"] = true;
            TempData["errorMsg"] = "...";
            TempData["Member"] = this.Member;
            return Page();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["isError"] = true;
        // etc.
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Why does the page set the preferred theme on `<body>` to dark mode when I'm submitting the page having this member TempData value set?

### Update

Here's the markup on the page (particularly what I'm doing with the error handling as that's what's in question here). I can't show screenshots of the page because it's proprietary.

Simply, I'm rendering a UI element to show the message:

```
@if(TempData["isError"] != null && (bool)TempData["isError"])
{
    <div class="callout callout-danger">
        <p>@TempData["errorMsg"].ToString()</p>
    </div>
}
```

Here's related markup as rendered before the dark mode issue:
[image]

Here's what it looks like after the dark mode thing happens:
[image]

Note the media query in the css has changed to a preference for dark mode. This is not included in my user code, I can't find `#dcdcdc` anywhere.

Comment: could you share some snippet of html code and also screenshot before and after to dark mode.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya I can share the HTML code but this is a proprietary system for internal use where I work so I can't do a screenshot; I will, however, include the before/after state from the dev console. Give me a minute.

Comment: Did you try in other browsers

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya I did. Based on the content of the page after it goes dark mode, I have to assume it was an error relating to my attempt to serialize `this.Member` into TempData.

Comment: Even I thought it might be the same as you pointed but I saw a catch block and then thoughtit should not cause issue, Anyway Try serializing the object before your assign.. somehting like below.
tempData[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
and use like this to render in UI. 
var memberData= (MemberObject)TempData["key"];